# When I run rails db:migrate on Heroku, the relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker, heroku

## Assumption

I am using `docker` to create an application. The first time I tried to deploy it to Heroku, it was deploying fine, but I got an error on `heroku run rails db:migrate`. I checked `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist` and found that the error was caused by the fact that other tables related to users were run first due to migration. I have tried everything, but I can't seem to solve the problem, so I am asking this question.

## What we want to achieve

I want to resolve the error and reflect the ``db

## Code

**Migration File Structure**

api/db/migrate

`20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb`

`20210626094529_create_posts.rb`

`20210626095339_create_post_items.rb`

`20220316090508_create_schedules.rb`

**20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb**

```rb
class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Required
      t.string :provider, :null => false, :default => "email"
      t.string :uid, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
      t.boolean  :allow_password_change, :default => false

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0, :null => false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      ## User Info
      t.string :name
      t.string :nickname
      t.string :image
      t.string :email
      t.boolean :guest

      ## Tokens
      t.json :tokens

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, [:uid, :provider],     unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

**20210626094529_create_posts.rb**

```rb
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :author
      t.string :image
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**20210626095339_create_post_items.rb**

```rb
class CreatePostItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :post_items do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.references :post, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :status

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**20220316090508_create_schedules.rb**

```rb
class CreateSchedules < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :schedules do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :color
      t.bigint :start
      t.bigint :end
      t.boolean :timed
      t.boolean :long_time
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :long_term_id
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_03_16_090508) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "post_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.boolean "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_post_items_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "author"
    t.string "image"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "color"
    t.bigint "start"
    t.bigint "end"
    t.boolean "timed"
    t.boolean "long_time"
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "long_term_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_schedules_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "provider", default: "email", null: false
    t.string "uid", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.boolean "allow_password_change", default: false
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "nickname"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "email"
    t.boolean "guest"
    t.json "tokens"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "post_items", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
  add_foreign_key "schedules", "users"
end
```

**puma**

```rb
workers Integer(ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 })

max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }


preload_app!

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

## Error

```
DEBUG -- :    (18.5ms)  CREATE TABLE "posts" ("id" bigserial primary key, "title" character varying, "author" character varying, "image" character varying, "user_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5b5ddfd518"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
)
DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(714769981607619105)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
・
・
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
・
・
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

## What we tried

1. Changed the date of `2022040403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb` migration file to `20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb`.
   We then reset all `DB`, did a migration, and started over.But the error remained the same.

```
database: app_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20210403234559  Devise token auth create users
   up     20210626094529  Create posts
   up     20210626095339  Create post items
   up     20220316090508  Create schedules
```

2. I wanted to reflect `20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb` on Heroku, so I ran `heroku run rails db:migrate VERSION=20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb`. When I run `token_auth_create_users.rb`, I get the following error

```
DEBUG -- :    (1.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(714769981607619105)
DEBUG -- :    (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(714769981607619105)
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError:

No migration with version number 20210403234559.
```

**Code executed by `heroku`**

`$ heroku login`

`$ heroku update beta`

`$ heroku plugins:install @heroku-cli/plugin-manifest`

`$ heroku create <App Name> --manifest`

`$ git push heroku master`

`$ heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<master key>`

`api $ heroku run rails db:migrate` Error

Comment: It feels to me like the migration creating the `users` table (`20210403234559 `) was never run on your Heroku production environment. Can you have a look at your production DB directly if that table exists?

Comment: @spickermann　　What do you mean by ``directly look at the production DB``? I haven't had a single successful ``heroku run rails db:migrate`` yet, so I don't think the table has been created.

Comment: It actually seems like the problem is in create_posts no? Do u have some ActiveRecord code that calls User model in there?

Comment: @JoelBlum I associated it with ``t.references :user, foreign_key: true``. However, Heroku should migrate in timestamp order, so I don't think it will be a problem. I'll add the code to the miogration file as well, just in case.

Comment: @JoelBlum And I'm getting 3 errors, so I guess ``20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb`` cannot run and posts, posts_items, schedules cannot read user_id. posts, posts_items, schedules cannot read user_id. I think the error is that posts, posts_items and schedules cannot read the user_id....

Comment: @spickermann ``devise``. Used for new registrations and user logins.

Comment: Is it possible that the migration `20210403234559` is not committed to version control?

Comment: @spickermann  I checked ``GitHub`` and there was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file from `20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb` to `00220403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb` after a re-push I used the `heroku run rails db:migrate` command and it worked.

1. `20210403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb` to `00220403234559_devise_token_auth_create_users.rb`
2. `$ rails db:migrate:reset`
3. `$ git push`
4. `$ heroku run rails db:migrate`

Thank you very much for all your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be useful to you. i did it

> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses the `schema_migrations` table to keep track of migrations with the timestamp as the version number.

You can do 2 things to fix this glitch.

1. Remove `20210403234559` from `schema_migrations` and retry.
2. Rename `20210403234559` to some other timestamp.